# what is the difference between with session and just using session in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

using
`with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess:`
doesnt give me an error
but if I use
`sess = tf.session(graph = g)`
I get an error

```
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    v1 = tf.Variable(1,name = "v1")
    v2 = tf.Variable(2,name = "v2")



with tf.session(graph = g) as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

above gives me no error

```
import tensorflow as tf


g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    v1 = tf.Variable(1,name = "v1")
    v2 = tf.Variable(2,name = "v2")


sess = tf.Session(graph = g)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

but this gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 300, in __init__
    fetch, allow_tensor=True, allow_operation=True))
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3490, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3574, in _as_graph_element_locked
    raise ValueError("Operation %s is not an element of this graph." % obj)
ValueError: Operation name: "init"
op: "NoOp"
 is not an element of this graph.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "maintest.py", line 14, in <module>
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 929, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1137, in _run
    self._graph, fetches, feed_dict_tensor, feed_handles=feed_handles)
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 471, in __init__
    self._fetch_mapper = _FetchMapper.for_fetch(fetches)
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 271, in for_fetch
    return _ElementFetchMapper(fetches, contraction_fn)
  File "/Users/wonjunson/gym/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 307, in __init__
    'Tensor. (%s)' % (fetch, str(e)))
ValueError: Fetch argument <tf.Operation 'init' type=NoOp> cannot be interpreted as a Tensor. (Operation name: "init"
op: "NoOp"
 is not an element of this graph.)
```

But, I don't see the big difference between them.

I'm guessing this is because I'm using `global_variables_initializer`. Since I only need to initialize variables in g.
But still, the variables are also included in `global_variables`, isnt it?
Or the variables are local in graph g?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you must have already read the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/graphs)

> Most TensorFlow programs start with a dataflow graph construction phase. In this phase, you invoke TensorFlow API functions that construct new tf.Operation (node) and tf.Tensor (edge) objects and add them to a tf.Graph instance.

i think if you change the second example to this then the `init` operation is part of the graph.

```
g = tf.Graph()

with g.as_default():
    v1 = tf.Variable(1,name = "v1")
    v2 = tf.Variable(2,name = "v2")
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer() # Part of the graph now


sess = tf.Session(graph = g)
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("D:/Development_Avecto/TensorFlow/output", sess.graph)
sess.run(init)
writer.close()
```

You can also visualize this in tensorboard

`tensorboard --logdir D:/Development_Avecto/TensorFlow/output`

[image]

Comment: I kind of get it but not 100% sure. 
sess = tf.Session(graph = g)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer()) then in this case, init is not inside the graph, is it correct? But if I do with tf.Session(graph = g) as sess: then the lines below happen inside the graph. is it right?

Comment: Yes. Both the operations and the data should be part of a graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can also restrict the session and graph context using `as_default()` to avoid the error:

```
self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph, config=tf_config)
with self.sess.as_default():
    with self.graph.as_default():
        self.sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```